# LineChart data not updating and crashing app

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-chart-kit

I am new to coding and this is my first full app build.

I trying to get the Line Chart component to update with the data that I am passing from another component. But, when I have <LineChart /> commented in it is crashing my app without an error message. I think the issue has something to do with the LineChartData not updating at the right time?

Does anyone have suggestions of how to get the LineChart to render correctly?

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { BarChart, LineChart } from "react-native-chart-kit";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";

import Colors from "../constants/Colors";
import NavBar from "../../NavBar";

const HealthData = () => {
  const [barChartData, setBarChartData] = useState(null);
  const [lineChartData, setLineChartData] = useState([]);
  const [savedHealthData, setSavedHealthData] = useState([]);
  const [triggerReload, setTriggerReload] = useState(false);

  const [energyData, setEnergyData] = useState([]);
  const [fatigueData, setFatigueData] = useState([]);
  const [motivationData, setMotivationData] = useState([]);

  // console.log("++++++++++  saved health data", savedHealthData);

  const dayOfWeekCounts = {
    Monday: 0,
    Tuesday: 0,
    Wednesday: 0,
    Thursday: 0,
    Friday: 0,
    Saturday: 0,
    Sunday: 0,
  };

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  useEffect(() => {
    if (triggerReload === true) {
      setTriggerReload(false);
    }

    const getSavedHealthData = async () => {
      try {
        const healthDataKeys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        const filteredKeys = healthDataKeys.filter((key) =>
          key.includes("HealthData")
        );
        const savedHealthDataArray = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(filteredKeys);
        // console.log("health data pulled down");

        const parsedData = savedHealthDataArray.map((data) =>
          JSON.parse(data[1])
        );
        console.log("parsed data===========", parsedData);

        setSavedHealthData(parsedData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error retrieving saved data:", error);
      }
    };

    getSavedHealthData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    calculateBarChart();

    const createLineChartData = () => {
      console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!! createLineChartData triggered");
      const newEnergyData = [];
      const newMotivationData = [];
      const newFatigueData = [];

      const energyDataPoint = [];
      const motivationDataPoint = [];
      const fatigueDataPoint = [];

      console.log("saved health data", savedHealthData);

      for (let i = 0; i < savedHealthData.length; i++) {
        let insideSavedHealthData = savedHealthData[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < insideSavedHealthData.length; j++) {
          const energyInfo = insideSavedHealthData[j].energyState;
          const motivationInfo = insideSavedHealthData[j].motivationState;
          const fatigueInfo = insideSavedHealthData[j].tirednessState;
          const dataKeyInfo = insideSavedHealthData[j].dataKey;

          newEnergyData.push([dataKeyInfo, energyInfo]);
          newMotivationData.push([dataKeyInfo, motivationInfo]);
          newFatigueData.push([dataKeyInfo, fatigueInfo]);

          // console.log("new energy data", newEnergyData);
          // console.log("new motivation data", newMotivationData);
          // console.log("new fatigue data", newFatigueData);
        }
      }

      newEnergyData.forEach((data) => {
        if (data[1] === false) {
          energyDataPoint.push([1, energyDataPoint.length + 1]);
          // 1 = yes
        } else {
          energyDataPoint.push([2, energyDataPoint.length + 1]);
          // -1 = no
        }
      });

      console.log("energy data point for loop", energyDataPoint);

      newMotivationData.forEach((data, i) => {
        if (data[1] === false) {
          motivationDataPoint.push([1, motivationDataPoint.length + 1]);
          // 1 = yes
        } else {
          motivationDataPoint.push([2, motivationDataPoint.length + 1]);
          // -1 = no
        }
      });

      console.log("motivation data point for loop", motivationDataPoint);

      newFatigueData.forEach((data, i) => {
        if (data[1] === false) {
          fatigueDataPoint.push([1, fatigueDataPoint.length + 1]);
        } else {
          fatigueDataPoint.push([2, fatigueDataPoint.length + 1]);
        }
      });

      console.log("fatigue data point for loop", fatigueDataPoint);

      setEnergyData(energyDataPoint);
      setMotivationData(motivationDataPoint);
      setFatigueData(fatigueDataPoint);
      console.log("after setting state in createLineChartData");

      //its breaking somewhere in this function
      // Update lineChartData state variable asynchronousl
    };

    createLineChartData();
  }, [savedHealthData]);

  // console.log("energy", energyData);
  // console.log("motivation", motivationData);
  // console.log("fatigue", fatigueData);

  const calculateBarChart = () => {
    console.log("~~~~~~~~~~~~ barchart triggered");
    for (let i = 0; i < savedHealthData.length; i++) {
      let insideSavedHealthData = savedHealthData[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < insideSavedHealthData.length; j++) {
        const dayOfWeek = insideSavedHealthData[j].dayOfWeek;
        dayOfWeekCounts[dayOfWeek] += 1;
      }
    }

    // Convert dayOfWeekCounts object to an array
    const countsArray = Object.values(dayOfWeekCounts);
    // console.log("COUNTTTTTS ARRRRRAAAYYYYY", countsArray);

    // Replace NaN values with null
    const sanitizedCountsArray = countsArray.map((count) =>
      isNaN(count) ? null : count
    );

    // Create the bar chart data using the counts array
    const chartData = {
      labels: ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: sanitizedCountsArray,
        },
      ],
    };

    setBarChartData(chartData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const takeDataMakeLineChart = () => {
      console.log("+++++++++++++++ entering takeDataMakeLineChart!");
      console.log("energyData:", energyData);
      console.log("motivationData:", motivationData);
      console.log("fatigueData:", fatigueData);
      try {
        console.log("entering try in takeDataMakeLineChart");
        const data = {
          labels: energyData.map((data) => data[1]),
          datasets: [
            {
              data: energyData.map((data) => data[2]),
              color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
              label: "Energy",
            },
            {
              data: motivationData.map((data) => data[2]),
              color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 255, 0, ${opacity})`,
              label: "Motivation",
            },
            {
              data: fatigueData.map((data) => data[0]),
              color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 255, ${opacity})`,
              label: "Fatigue",
            },
          ],
        };

        console.log("data:", data);
        setLineChartData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in takeDataMakeLineChart:", error);
      }
    };

    takeDataMakeLineChart();
  }, [fatigueData]);

  console.log("************************************************");
  console.log(lineChartData);
  console.log("************************************************");

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.daysOfWeekChart}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Days of the week you workout</Text>
          {barChartData && (
            <BarChart
              data={barChartData}
              width={380}
              height={400}
              yAxisLabel=""
              chartConfig={{
                backgroundColor: "#F7F2FE",
                backgroundGradientFrom: "#F7F2FE",
                backgroundGradientTo: "#F7F2FE",
                decimalPlaces: 0,
                color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
                style: {
                  borderRadius: 16,
                },
              }}
              style={{
                marginVertical: 8,
                borderRadius: 16,
              }}
            />
          )}
        </View>

        <View style={styles.correlationChart}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Correlation equals causation?</Text>

          {lineChartData && (
            <LineChart
              data={lineChartData}
              width={380}
              height={400}
              chartConfig={{
                backgroundGradientFrom: "#fff",
                backgroundGradientTo: "#fff",
                color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
                strokeWidth: 2,
                barPercentage: 0.5,
                useShadowColorFromDataset: false,
                decimalPlaces: 0,
              }}
              style={{
                marginVertical: 8,
                borderRadius: 16,
              }}
            />
          )}

          <View style={styles.keyContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.keyTitle}>Key</Text>

            <View styles={styles.energyContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.energyKey}>Energy</Text>
            </View>

            <View styles={styles.motivationContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.motivationKey}>Motivation</Text>
            </View>

            <View styles={styles.tirednessContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.tirednessKey}>Tiredness</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.navBar}>
        <NavBar />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HealthData;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 60,
    backgroundColor: "#F7F2FE",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#333",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  daysOfWeekChart: {
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  correlationChart: {
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  keyContainer: {
    borderColor: "#333",
    borderWidth: 2,
    alignItems: "center",
    width: 151,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    height: 170,
  },
  keyTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#333",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  energyContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  energyKey: {
    backgroundColor: "#C8BFD4",
    borderRadius: 5,
    lineHeight: 30,
    width: 101,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  motivationContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  motivationKey: {
    backgroundColor: "#C8BFD4",
    borderRadius: 5,
    lineHeight: 30,
    width: 100,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  tirednessContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  tirednessKey: {
    backgroundColor: "#C8BFD4",
    borderRadius: 5,
    lineHeight: 30,
    width: 100,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  navBar: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    width: "100%",

    backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
  },
});
```